# Error showing some effects

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

I have been playing Skyrim for quite some time now and when I heard they updated the Skyrim online version, I downloaded it.

I played it a bit and noticed a bug that happened on single player and the "multiplayer" - whenever I looked at some stuff while in first person, my screen started flashing yellow.

It almost always happened with fire, spell (in the hand), and a bit randomly.

This has never happened before, and I had about 150 hours spent with the same PC specification. Now I have replaced changed the specification and hoped for something better but this doesn't appear to be the case.

Things I have tried:

- deleting the Skyrim online files
- uninstalling Skyrim and downloading again

Specification of my computer:

Display: AMD Radeon HD 6800 Series(2548 mb).
Processor: Intel Core 2 Due CPU E6550 @2.33 GHz
Memory: 3582 (DDR 2)
Operating system: Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit

I have Direct X 11 installed.

Sorry if there's not enough information, I was reading it all from the dxdiag file.

Comment: might be worthwhile posting up a screenshot of the graphical errors you're experiencing to further clarify the problem

Comment: its just pure yellow, do you need a pic for that?

Comment: You're experimenting with a mod that's under constant development that tries to hack multiplayer functionality into a single-player game. You probably just hit a bug with the new version of the mod. What makes you think we can help better than you reporting the bug to the mod author?

Comment: I deleted the mod years ago, i don't have it now.

Comment: Okay, here's the thing: This question really needs more information. Did you use this savegame with Skyrim Online? How did you delete the game? Did you delete the config files (which are not in the same place)? Did you delete the mod's files manually, or just reinstall over top of them? You say a years have passed (NB Skyrim is less than a year old)—has this been happening ever since, or only with this savegame, or has it only just started happening? We need a better description of your situation and the problem. Just adding a bounty to an incomplete question isn't going to help.

Comment: I used a whole new save game.
I deleted the game via steam.
I deleted the mod's files manually.
I didn't really meant years, a few months.

Comment: Okay, so could you edit the question to give a more complete picture of the situation and timeline? Comments are "below the fold", so putting all relevant info in the question, and sometimes reorganising it, really is necessary.

Comment: I'd rather do a make a new one later.   I'm getting some new "specs" for my PC anyway (cuz really DDR 2?)
I will try it then and if it doesn't work I shall make a new question with more details and pictures and stuff.   
or at least that's what's in my imagination.

Answer (score -1):

A lot of people are sharing the same problem. Are you having Shadow flickering or Texture flickering? As for shadow flickering there is no current fix. Texture Flickering is very odd. On my 1st PC just doing a clean install of my video drivers fixed it (GTX580). That means, uninstalling the video card, then downloading lastest drivers. On my other PC, which has a 250 just disabling AA fixed it, here I still get some flickering, but it has been reduced greatly. Give this 2 a try. This website has a nice list of bugs and fixes http://www.gamingreality.com/2011/11/skyrim-fixes-for-bugs-crashes-sound.html

Comment: That is totally off-topic. This smells distinctly of spam, especially considering how many ads are plastered on the linked page.

Comment: I got this while looking for the problem myself...its not exactly my response but its the answer to the question presented.

Comment: It's not an answer to the question. It's a problem cause by a mod called Skyrim Online. That link is to a list of problems and fixes for unmodded Skyrim.